# Snap Monad, LiftIO and ghc 7.4.1

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm trying to get some code that was working in ghc 7.0.4 work with 7.4.1.

It appears to me that old way of accessing IO from inside the Snap moand no longer typechecks.

In ghc 7.0.4, the documented way of accessing IO compiles.

```
a :: Snap ()
a = liftIO fireTheMissiles
```

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.8.1/doc/html/Snap-Core.html

In GHC 7.4.1,

```
No instance for (MonadIO Snap)
  arising from a use of `liftIO'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (MonadIO Snap)
```

I'm curious what an attractive work around would be.

Comment: GHC version should not affect this. Can you compare library versions between your 7.0 install and 7.4 install? Try `ghc-pkg-7.0.4 list snap-core` and `ghc-pkg-7.4.1 list snap-core`.

Comment: That is very strange. All Snap handler-like types for sure have MonadIO instances. This includes Snap, Handler and Initializer (even though the last is not a handler-like type). Can you paste your code somewhere so we can try and run it?

Comment: @DanielWagner 

ghc-pkg-7.0.4 list snap-core 
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.4/package.conf.d
/home/zaki/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.4/package.conf.d
   snap-core-0.8.1


ghc-pkg list snap-core
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.4.1/package.conf.d
/home/zaki/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.4.1/package.conf.d
   snap-core-0.8.1

Comment: @zmanian Well, I can't reproduce it. I've got GHC 7.4.1 and snap-core-0.8.1 installed, and ghci doesn't complain about `:t liftIO (return ()) :: Snap ()`. So your problem is elsewhere. Give us enough code that we can reproduce the problem and we'll try to help you understand it.

Comment: I figured out whats going on. I have some sort of dependency nightmare going on in my cabal after upgrading to prerelease haskell platform. I should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that you have conflicting versions of some package (likely `transformers`). Snap is likely built against a different version (perhaps 0.2.2) while you're trying to use version 0.3. As a result, there's no instance for the `MonadIO` that you have in scope (from 0.3). This is just a guess, but I've seen the same thing occur a number of times.

One of the easiest ways to avoid this situation is to cabalize your code. cabal will warn you if you try to use different versions of the same package.